# Run Spring context using Play Framework and Gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, playframework

Currently I have simple spring rest application which situated in separate gradle module. Is it possible to add gradle module with play application which will run spring context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - Spring requires a servlet container, Play is not a servlet container. It's like asking if you could run a Spring REST application in WordPress, they're completely different technologies.